# How can I reduce, compress <Image> size in axios fetch? - React Native

Tags: react-native, api, axios

I get my products from API but photo sizes are really big. I want to compress them and reduce their sizes. I am sharing my get request and flatList. Any help will be appreciated!

[image: get request]

[image: my flatlist]

[image: my flatlistitem]

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please try to include relevant code snippets as actual text inside the question, to make it easier for visiting users to understand and implement themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `manipulateAsync` function of [react-native-image-manipulator](https://github.com/pontusab/react-native-image-manipulator) library.

You can use this example function:

```js
import * as ImageManipulator from 'react-native-image-manipulator';

export const compressImage = async (uri) => {
    const manipImage = await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(
        uri, [], { compress: 0.3 }
    );
    return manipImage;
}
```

You can use the compress option to compress your photo.